# avoid data lagging problem when bind inside table with linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I'm using CODE first approach, I have defined tables like this

```
[Table("SAMPLE_BASE_TABLE")]
public partial class SampleBaseTable
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Sample_Foriegn_Key_Id { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("Sample_Foriegn_Key_Id")]
    public List<SampleSubTable> SampleSubTable { get; set; }
}

[Table("SAMPLE_SUB_TABLE")]
public partial class SampleSubTable
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Sample_Foriegn_Key_Id { get; set; }
}
```

Then I defined View model to bind these table data following way

```
[DataContract]
public class SampleViewModel
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    [DataMember]
    public IEnumerable<SubSampleViewModel> SubSampleViewModels { set; get; }      

}

[DataContract]
public class SampleViewModel
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

then I try to bind this data following way

```
public IEnumerable<SampleViewModel> GetList()
    {
        
        var list = 
           (
            from sample in _context.SampleBaseTable             
            select new SampleViewModel
            {
                Id = sample.Id,                  
                SubSampleViewModel = sample.SubSampleViewModels.Select(oc => new SubSampleViewModel
                {
                    Id = oc.Id,
                    Name = oc.Name,
                    
                }),    


            }).DistinctBy(x=>x.Id);

        var cnt = list.Count();

        var final = list
            .OrderByDescending(o => o.Id)
            .Skip((dto.Page - 1) * dto.TotalNumberOfItemsPerPage)
            .Take(dto.TotalNumberOfItemsPerPage);     

        final.ForEach(fe => fe.RecordCount = cnt);

        return final;

    }
```

this approach working fine with small data set with no issues. but if per one row of SAMPLE_BASE_TABLE table value has 100 more SAMPLE_SUB_TABLE rows, then it's lagging more than 30 seconds.

How to reduce the time make this quicker call

Comment: What is `DistinctBy`?

Comment: I'm asking because this query is totally ineffective, especially if you are using something exotic.